# How to make a variable input be any number I put in (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding and am having trouble with one of my first projects.

So I have to basically type a number and then have that number spit out some answers involving things like addition and multiplication. (ex. if I put in 5, one of the answers is to simply multiply that 5 by 30. Or another adds it).

The issue is that the only way I can get that number to be different and give the corresponding answers is if I go into the code and change the integer assigned to the variable, which is pretty counterintuitive.

I've tried deleting the variable, setting = 0, moving it around; nothing is working.

```
stocks = 0;
investment = stocks * 30;
charges = investment * .015;
total = charges + investment;
cout << "Cindy, how much are you investing?";
cin >> stocks;
cout << endl;
```

some of the code there. Line in question is the "stocks = 0;" one. After that, it's the other variables that would be output with their associated variables. Any help would be appreciated, I hope this makes sense for what I'm asking! Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask for the number first, then do math. This is a scary before the horse as you can get.

Comment: put the cout prompt and cin before you do the calculations

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how expressions work in C++, and maybe confusing them with how you define them in mathematics. Mathematics often defines expressions and then you change the values of variables to calculate. In C++, the expression is defined in the code, but you must give your variables an actual value first. Unless you turn them into a function or lambda, but I would say you're not ready for that yet. As someone who is new to coding, it's highly recommended to follow an introductory book that explains the basic concepts, rather than just making guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cin the number.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int stocks;
    std::cout << "Cindy, how much are you investing?";
    std::cin >> stocks;
    investment = stocks * 30;
    charges = investment * .015;
    total = charges + investment;
    std::cout << "The total charges would be " << total << "." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add some explanation to your answer. In particular, the importance of reading the value of variables ***before*** using them in calculations.

Comment: ok @AdrianMole , thanks. Will surely add that.

Comment: This code [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/PqsvbGcjM).